# java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Data source mongodb does not support microbatch processing

Tags: mongodb, azure, pyspark, azure-databricks, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

I'm trying to perform read/write streaming data from CosmosDB API for MongoDB into databricks pyspark and gettting error java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Data source mongodb does not support microbatch processing. 
Please help anyone how can we achieve data streaming in pyspark.

````
        from pyspark.streaming import StreamingContext
        from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
        from pyspark.sql.functions import *
        from pyspark.sql.streaming import *
        from pyspark.sql.types import StringType,BooleanType,DateType,StructType,LongType,IntegerType 
        
        spark = SparkSession.\
                builder.\
                appName("streamingExampleRead").\
                config('spark.jars.packages', 'org.mongodb.spark:mongo-spark-connector:10.0.0').\
                getOrCreate()
 
sourceConnectionString = <primary connection string of cosmosDB API for MongoDB isntance>
sourceDb = <your database name>
sourceCollection =  <yourcollection name>       
        
        dataStreamRead=(
                        spark.readStream.format("mongodb")
                        .option('spark.mongodb.connection.uri', sourceConnectionString)
                        .option('spark.mongodb.database', sourceDb) \
                        .option('spark.mongodb.collection', sourceCollection) \
                        .option('spark.mongodb.change.stream.publish.full.document.only','true') \
                        .option("forceDeleteTempCheckpointLocation", "true") \                            
                        .load()
                        )
        
        
        display(dataStreamRead)
        
        
        query2=(dataStreamRead.writeStream \
          .outputMode("append") \
          .option("forceDeleteTempCheckpointLocation", "true") \
          .format("console") \
          .trigger(processingTime='1 seconds')
          .start().awaitTermination());
       
        Getting following error: 
        java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Data source mongodb does not support microbatch processing.
            at org.apache.spark.sql.errors.QueryExecutionErrors$.microBatchUnsupportedByDataSourceError(QueryExecutionErrors.scala:1579)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution$$anonfun$1.applyOrElse(MicroBatchExecution.scala:123)
        
        Data source mongodb does not support microbatch processing.
        === Streaming Query ===
        Identifier: [id = 78cfcef1-19de-40f4-86fc-847109263ee9, runId = d2212e1f-5247-4cd2-9c8c-3cc937e2c7c5]
        Current Committed Offsets: {}
        Current Available Offsets: {}
        
        Current State: INITIALIZING
        Thread State: RUNNABLE```
````

Comment: As mentioned in the error micro-batch processing is not supported. Look at this Databricks community question https://community.databricks.com/s/question/0D58Y00009J5Dn7SAF/trying-to-stream-data-from-cosmosdb-for-mongoapi-readstreamwritestream-into-databricks-getting-error-javalangunsupportedoperationexception-data-source-mongodb-does-not-support-microbatch-processing

Answer (score 0):

Try using `trigger(continuous="1 second")` instead of  `trigger(processingTime='1 seconds')`.

Comment: Please provide some explanation as what was the issue in OP's code and how the solution that you have suggested solves the problem.